# Can't send message from Coordinator to end device? [MiWi Pro]

Tags: networking, embedded, protocols, pic, microchip

I am using MiWi Pro wireless networking protocol and I was running some tests with unicast function, but I encountered a problem.

**Unicast Main Issue:**
The end device doesn't receive the messages from its parent coordinator whether the unicast message is sent using the short or long address of the end device.

So let's say we have this configuration.

**Coordinator1** has short address of 0300 AND
**End_Device1** has short address of 0301

So these are the things I noticed ..

Sending a unicast message from **Coordinator1** to **End_Device1** either by short or long address doesn't work. However, sending a uincast message from the **End_Device1** to **Coordinator1** works fine.

I also noticed when you send the message from **Coordinator1** to **End_Device1**, **Coordinator1** receives the message even though its the one who sent it. It's really strange because End_Device1 should be receiving the message.

What do you think is preventing the parent coordinator from communicating with its end device and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: Did anyone encounter the same problem?

Comment: After 4 days of trying different things I still can't get the coordinator to send unicast messages to end devices.

Answer (score 0):

Coordinator1 if it's the root coordinator it must have the address 0000. you may have some routing problem otherwise.

Are you sure about the address of the end device ? The library is quite confusing on it. I've got a similar problem up to the point I realize the address I toke for the device was actually not the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

probably try to send packets using the permanent address of the RFD device because if there is change in network the short address can be varied so use MiApp_UnicastAddress( longAddressRfd, true, true ) here the 2nd parameter in this function is The boolean to indicate if the destination address above is  permanent address or alternative network address.1st parameter is the long address  and third parameter is a boolean to indicate the security was enabled or not.try this